# How to start a terminator instance always with a set of terminals (each one in a different directory) in one window

Tags: command-line, terminator

I want to open the same set of directory locations in one terminator window as multiple terminals every time by default (or when I run a script). I think it could be done via profiles or layouts. [man terminator_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminator_config) was not very helpful.

Comment: Check this out: https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1157422